# Cocoa - Where does NSCoding save?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscoding

what is the default saving location of NSCoding protocol?

Also, is there any way to change such a default location to say, the folder where the .app file is located?

Comment: you should read this docu: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly write your encoded object data encoded according NSCoding to a file using NSKeyedArchiver

Like this:

```
BOOL result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:yourObject toFile:filename];
```

With `filename` you can choose your file location (you may set it to the documents directory if you are on iOS).

**EDIT 1:**
If you'd like to store in into NSUserDefault... do:

```
NSData *yourObjectAsNSData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourObject];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourObjectAsNSData forKey:@"aKey"]
```

Comment: What if I use archivedDataWithRootObject:object ? Does the toFile: parameter still apply?

I tried it but couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Tried: 

NSString *path = @"file";
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:path] forKey:@"savedArray"];

which leads to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error + warning that I am making a pointer from integer without a cast..

Comment: wrong wrong. you try to store the BOOL "result" in your NSUserDefaults. That will crash!. I'll update my answer ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what I am currently doing. What I would like to know is if it is possible to know where the data is being saved on disk, and if I can change that path to the application path, using the code as per your edit 1?

Comment: Nope. When using NSUserdefaults the sore and the store location will be given by the OS. So, if you'd like to have a different "file" you need to write the data directly to a file as shown in the first example.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. Just a quick question then, if I use the first method example that you gave me, how would I go about unarchieving the data? I found : 

[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] and 
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:] 

Is there a way that I can use them both together? Cheers !